# Why one gramm of O and one gramm of O2 icludes same amount of oxygen atoms?

Tags: stoichiometry

So there is a problem I can't understand why one gram of O and one gram of O2 includes same amount of oxygen atoms.

Comment: Which of the following contains most oxygen atoms?a) 1,0 g O-atomeja, b) 1,0 g O2(g), c) 1,0 g O3(g). So there is clear question. And the right answer is that all of them includes same amount. And i don't understand how i can count this, because if i count in my way answer is wrong,

Comment: @paracetamol I guess I see your point, but this question somehow reminds me of "1kg of feathers vs 1kg of lead" problem:)

Comment: @Daria They all have the same number of *atoms*. Number of *particles*, will be different though ;)

Comment: @DariaKostiniuk No no, that's not what we meant. If it helps, one can show it analytically, e.g. presenting number of oxygen atoms as following: $$\begin{align}N(\ce{O}) &= n(\ce{O}) \times N_A = \\ &= \frac{x \times m(\ce{O_x}) \times N_A}{M(\ce{O_x})} = \\ &= \frac{x \times m(\ce{O_x}) \times N_A}{x \times M(\ce{O})} = \\ &= \mathrm{const}\end{align}$$

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28615/do-i-have-to-consider-the-molecular-mass-of-the-oxygen-atom-or-the-diatomic-oxyg https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23808/why-is-o2-enough-to-form-a-mole-of-oxygen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Would 2 C₂ be 2 moles of diatomic carbon, or 4 moles of carbon?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/would-2-c%e2%82%82-be-2-moles-of-diatomic-carbon-or-4-moles-of-carbon)

Comment: Suppose you are able to put $1.0$ gram Oxygen atom in a flask. Now you order all atoms of this sample to join to another one, so as to make couples. After that you weigh the content of you flask. it will have the same weight.

Answer (score 7):

I think this question needs an eye-opener in non-chemical terms.

Counter-question: What contains more chestnuts?

a) 1 kg of "Cn" (chestnuts)

[image: photo by Cornelia Kopp, https://flic.kr/p/N97ypT, CC BY]

b) 1 kg of "Cn<sub>2</sub>"

[image]

b) 1 kg of "Cn<sub>3</sub>"

[image]

c) 1 kg of "Cn<sub>4</sub>"

[image]